# Find Proxy Server using Command Line

Tags: command-line, proxy

Someone's set up a proxy on my machine and I want to know what it is. Is there a way to find the proxy server using the command line and not the GUI?

Comment: Does `echo $HTTP_PROXY` do anything?

Comment: I notice you had mentioned you were using 15.04 in your original post. Please consider upgrading to 16.04 because 15.04 has gone EOL.

Comment: Does the command `gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy host` return anything?

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of: https://serverfault.com/questions/278189/how-can-i-find-out-which-proxy-server-is-used-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For any system-wide proxy for HTTP, you can check the value of `http_proxy` environment variable:

```
echo "$http_proxy"
```

For HTTPS:

```
echo "$https_proxy"
```

Similarly, there are `ftp_proxy`, `socks_proxy` for serving the exact purpose of their names. There is also `all_proxy` for setting proxy for all these protocols at once. Just to note, `no_proxy` unsets proxy for any specific addresses of any (or all) given protocol. Just for sake of completeness, you might want to check the uppercase version of these variables too, although the lowercases are standard for `*_proxy` environment variables (only environment variables i am aware of that are lowercased).

Note that, these will show any system-wide proxy setting, not application-specific. For example, `firefox`, or `apt` can have their own proxy settings irrespective of any global one. Some applications do not honor these variables too (e.g. specific `gnome` apps use `gsettings`), so YMMV.

Comment: After I run 'echo "$http_proxy" ' it shows yust one blank row, is that mean that I don't have proxy on my server?

Comment: @SkulaSadam Check my edits.

Answer (score 12):

Attempt an http connection to the outside:

```
wget http://google.com
```

You'll see something like this as a result:

```
--2017-06-12 13:02:53--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 172.217.11.142, 2607:f8b0:4002:810::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|172.217.11.142|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 authenticationrequired
Location: http://192.168.254.99:9090/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/plugin?target=Auth&reason=Auth&ClientID=3130909038&ttl=600&url=aHR0cDovL2dvb2dsZS5jb20v&rnd=1497286973 [following]
--2017-06-12 13:02:53--  http://192.168.254.99:9090/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/plugin?target=Auth&reason=Auth&ClientID=3130909038&ttl=600&url=aHR0cDovL2dvb2dsZS5jb20v&rnd=1497286973
Connecting to 192.168.254.99:9090... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 authenticationrequired
```

Your proxy server in this case is found after the 302 authentication required.
http://192.168.254.99:9090/

Answer (score 10):

In Linux, you can use this to check the proxies defined in the system

```
env | grep proxy
```

Comment: env | grep -i proxy

Answer (score 5):

check the file :

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
cat /etc/environment
```

To Modify contents of file (remove everything from apt.conf for no proxy and only proxy sentences from environment)!

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Comment: `gedit` is a GUI program. How does this avoid using the GUI?

Comment: use `cat` then @Zacharee1.. i said gedit so OP can also edit it.

Comment: `gedit` might not even be installed, as this could be a server installation. `nano` and `vim` are both command line text editors.

Comment: @Zacharee1 hmm ..they r universal.I will edit solution thanx

Comment: Also, the first path doesn't actually exist on my system, and the second only includes a PATH variable.

Comment: @Zanna i edited

Comment: Removing everything in `/etc/environment` will break PATH and possibly other configurations. Please don't do that.

Comment: @Zacharee1 again edited..sry for mistakes

Comment: You should also explain what to look for. `apt.conf` doesn't exist on my system (and actually needs to be manually created to fix `apt-get` through a proxy), and I wouldn't know what to look for in `environment`.

Comment: @Zacharee1 unity containts/created apt.conf file when proxy is applied through network settings where as other system has a folder apt.conf.d (i dont know much about it detail) but i set the proxy settings for terminal through that environment has files like http_proxy=.....!!

Answer (score 2):

```
# netstat -na
```

OR, if you think/guess any proxy server then grep it to confirm,
e.g.

```
# netstat -na |grep <ProxyGuess IP>
```

Comment: these your answer does not tell what to look for exactly in the first half. and it does not answer the central part of the question of "i want to know what it is" because you are assuming something central must already know in order to get the answer.