# Cannot Load Sites unless connected to VPN

Tags: networking, firefox, google-chrome, vpn

I cannot access many websites including our own office web portals without using VPN. I tried using `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`, and I also attempted to to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to add: `source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*`

Furthermore, interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

The primary network interface on the device:

```
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp
```

Still I cannot access websites, web portals etc.

The output of `ip a` returns to me the following:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 68:f7:28:d3:d4:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:e0:c5:3a:7d:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.107/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 85831sec preferred_lft 85831sec
    inet6 fe80::f9d:3b03:c8d4:43e3/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:2e:cd:a6:65 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br-818882f39971: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:da:11:16:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-818882f39971
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br-f69c46d593ea: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:b9:fa:61:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-f69c46d593ea
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

`nslookup google.com`:

```
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.203.174
Name:   google.com
Address: 2404:6800:4009:803::200e
```

Comment: What OS version are you using, browser, and what is your network information. `ip a` and `more /etc/resolv.conf` are a good start.

Comment: Also, what are example websites, and can you locate them by using `nslookup google.com` - you might need to install `inettools` or some alternate package.

Comment: Vinay, I have [edited](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1241314/edit) your question to include the output of your `ip a` command - once approved, we can cleanup your comments. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1241314/edit) your question to include the nameserver you have in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file as well. Out of curiosity, if you perform `nslookup google.com` what is the returned IP address, and can you successfully `ping` the IP address?

Comment: Lastly - and sorry for the spam - can you output an image of your Wireless NIC via the GUI? You can [edit the settings](https://vitux.com/ubuntu-network-configuration/) via the GUI. I'm curious to see if "Auto-Connect to VPN" of if your DNS servers are hard-set.

Comment: nslookup google.com results added to post, i can ping google.com but i cannot access few websites and portal

Comment: Extended comment thread, I'll go ahead and add "an answer" to this comment, and we can work from there.

Comment: @DankyNanky Waiting for your response,Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have posted some steps I would take in diagnosing this - of course, ignoring the "have you restarted your PC and router" - which *is* a valid step! Comment on the answer if you need to discuss.

Comment: Vinay - any traction on this?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: "I cannot access few websites and portal"

If you are not able to access some websites, there may be an ACL on these networks (such as a public IP limitation), or you could have routing issues to the subnets in which they resolve.

For example, if you can't reach `mytest.portal.business.com` and it resolves as `10.1.1.3`, then this would stipulate it's an internally hosted service that you've got a static record for. If a large portion of websites work (such as YouTube, Google, AskUbuntu) but a subset don't, this would indicate more of an issue with networking/routing than the system in itself.

---

If you're able to successfully resolve (via `nslookup`) and test an ICMP connection (`ping`) then this denotes you have network connectivity; if you perform `sudo apt upgrade -y` and it functions, you have networking connectivity and this brings the issue down to an **application fault**.

In this instance, it appears that you're in fact using WiFi as your connection medium, as denoted by your `ip a` which resulted in:

```
wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:e0:c5:3a:7d:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.107/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 85831sec preferred_lft 85831sec
    inet6 fe80::f9d:3b03:c8d4:43e3/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

## DHCP

First and foremost, I would confirm that you're getting DHCP on the same logical subnet as other clients that are working - this is simple, compare `ip a` on hosts to ensure you're in the same range. For example, this could be `192.168.0.1` or `172.20.20.1` but (usually) neither together.

To view your DHCP configuration (if you're using `netplan`) you can run `ls -l /var/lib/NetworkManager`, and what is most important is `cat` your lease file - for me:

```
cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/internal-16fa33b0-caa7-3219-a480-331e166fd77c-eno2.lease 
# This is private data. Do not parse.
ADDRESS=192.168.0.116
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ROUTER=192.168.0.1
SERVER_ADDRESS=192.168.0.1
T1=42600
T2=74550
LIFETIME=85200
DNS=208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220
DOMAINNAME=loopback.local
CLIENTID=01b42e9933fa61
```

Make sure in the DHCP lease, your router IP address **is your local router** - and not another IP address you cannot route to without a VPN connection (additional adapter).

## DNS

The first test is to ensure your DNS is not the fault, run `resolvectl status | grep "DNS Servers"` to list the current server you're using; you can update this to be 
something such as `1.1.1.1` as a test:

```
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

## Proxy Server

At this point in time, if you're not able to resolve websites (well, load), move on to diagnosing if your system is using a proxy: `env | grep proxy` - if you're using a proxy, it'll return an answer. You can find [more answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/924676/212930) on diagnosing proxies here.

## Firewalls

On Ubuntu, you can disable the Firewall temporarily to see if this is contributing. For `firewalld` the command is:

```
systemctl stop firewalld   # Disables the Firewall
systemctl status firewalld # Gets the firewall's status
```

For `ufw`, perform the following:

```
sudo ufw status verbose # Gets the firewall's status
sudo ufw disable        # Disables the Firewall
```

You could further diagnose this by performing a `netstat` or a Wireshark capture, if you believed this a networking issue.

## Application Diagnostics

From this point, if your browser *still* doesn't want to load, load an additional browser such as Vivaldi, and see if the same issue occurs. You can run the application via the terminal to get output - or using inbuilt console.

Lastly - as I had this happen to me once - I had a strange "profile" issue with my wireless network. I had to [remove the network](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43763119/8505596) and reconnect/establish to get it working.