# Mirror Failure - Default Redirect

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, updates, 20.04

I an running into a common issue with trying to maintain and install packages for Ubuntu 20.04, with the following error being returned:

> 0% [Connecting to au.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:388:30bc:cafe::beef)]

So, first and foremost I just blamed `IPv6` as the issue, so went to disable this with the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4
```

Adding the value:

```
Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";
```

Then I proceeded with the following to disable IPv6 on the system entirely:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
```

Then added the following into the configuration file:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Then I re-loaded:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Then, I ran an `apt update -y` to ensure my packages are updated. Here I an seeing that the repository IPv4 is now being shown, but I still cannot connect to it:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]       
Hit:2 https://apt.enpass.io stable InRelease                                                                            
Hit:3 https://packages.cisofy.com/community/lynis/deb stable InRelease                                                                         
Err:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                            
  Could not connect to au.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (202.158.214.106), connection timed out
Err:5 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to au.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:6 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to au.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
```

So as far as I understand, I am being redirected to my nearest mirror that's being best-sourced for my system. How/is there a method wherein I can test to see the availability of the mirror, or even default to another location based on a failure to connect?

Comment: I [did a little diagnostics](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241325/212930) on the mirrors for Proxies and Firewall.

Comment: I can't reach the au ones too, it could be down for some time; in the mean time you can replace them with `http://archive.ubuntu.com` or any `http://XX.archive.ubuntu.com` where XX=country code, in your `sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

It weirdly looks like a "common" problem for Australian users going to the Australian mirrors: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/162865  Per the bug ticket, contact mirrors@ubuntu.com with your traceroutes and debugging.

In the meantime, you can swap out the mirrors in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` for a non-Australian mirror.

Comment: Thanks. This question was more on does the OS handle these issues automatically.