# nameserver change breaks server

Tags: network-manager, dns, netplan, routing

I am using **Ubuntu 20.04.1** LTS. I have very limited knowledge on how to set the network configuration after the installation of the server.

I run a small subnet with one static IP server on it next to my dhcp home subnet.
I have `pihole` running wich then Points to `unbound` for dnsquery.

I then set `nameserver` in netplan to `127.0.0.1` for local dnsquery.
Static IP server is now without Connection to homesubnet/internet, i can ping the server but hte server can't ping back.

IP route show gives me no info at all. I get the feeling that the server can't find the router? `Gateway` is set.

Comment: I am a little confused. You've applied a Netplan to your server, and now other devices have DNS access, but you don't think this server can route - is that correct, or am I drunk? If you post output of `ip a` and `ip route` we can have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave up on static IP.
After a lot of google and trial / error:

1 - Start dhcp server on router for subnet, bind server mac.

2 - Wiped /etc/netplan/01-netcfg..

3 - find out dhcp renderer.

4 - fix netplan to start dhcp.
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
en01:
dhcp4: true

5 - netplan try -> netplan apply

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am interpreting your question correctly, but a few things to help test if you can in fact see your router from your server.

Because NetPlan now is the default manager, we can ignore `/etc/resolv.conf`, however to view or modify on Ubuntu you can set your DNS settings via `/etc/resolv.conf` as follows:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search internal-network.local
```

If you are using `resolv` and not `Netplan`, point this at your DNS provider (in this question, PiHole I surmise), and restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl status resolvconf.service
```

From here, you can then test to see if you can reach your router or DNS provider. If you simply `ping` the IP address of your destination (removing DNS from the equation) you should see if you can hit your L2 next-hop. You can find this out quite easily:

```
ip a | grep default

default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno2 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno2 proto dhcp metric 100
```

(Noting your ranges will vary)

From there perform a basic `ping -c 1 192.168.0.1` to ensure you have connectivity. From here you can start to validate that you have L2 network access.

## Your Question

> I get the feeling that the server cannot find the router

This is pretty open. If you've configured your DHCP leases (or your static routes correctly) then that should be fine. On your server, [have a look at the netplan](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241325/212930) configuration and ensure you've set it correctly.

Run `cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/internal...` (noting the file is unique, use `tab` to auto-complete) to see your DHCP data:

```
# This is private data. Do not parse.
ADDRESS=192.168.0.9
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ROUTER=192.168.0.1
SERVER_ADDRESS=192.168.0.1
T1=42600
T2=74550
LIFETIME=85200
DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
DOMAINNAME=internal-network.local
CLIENTID=01b42e9933fa61
```

If you've got the correct information here (`ROUTER`, `NETMASK` and `SERVER_ADDRESS`) then your problem is something else. A simple ICMP ping will denote whether you've got access to your router. If you're in the same logical network (I'm going to *guess* you're on a convention /24 range (255.255.255.0/24)) then you should also be see your DNS setup without the requirement to route.

> IP route show gives me no info at all. I get the feeling that the server can't find the router?

This will give you all the information you require. If your DNS server is not within the same broadcast domain,  you'll need to route to it. If this is in the same logical subnet then you should be able to abide by the default route on your box (an assumption is being made you have 1 logical NIC) - and even if not, as long as `default` knows how to route to $x you're fine.

The question here is does your *server* have the capacity to route *via* your router to the internet. Start by identifying your routers internal IP address and see if you can get to it - then, try an internet address:

```
m-(~)-(15 files, 1.5Mb)--> traceroute 1.1.1.1
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 64 hops max
  1   192.168.0.1  0.505ms  0.395ms  0.301ms 
  2   58.162.26.2  1.810ms  1.904ms  1.923ms
```

The first hop is my router, and then out to the internet. If you've got dual NICs, you might want to add a route:

```
ip route add 1.1.1.1/32 via 192.168.0.1
```

Retest this single host and see if your route changes.

Comment: Resolvconf is not a substitute for netplan.  I don't think you should mention it at all here.