# DNS on Ubuntu 22.04 is failing. (using netplan)

Tags: 22.04, dns, netplan

I just install a **new** Virtual machine using Hyper-V server, and [ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso](https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso)

After install, I notice that DNS is not functional.  I have seen multiple question/answers about replacing `/etc/resolv.conf` by another version but NetworkManager is not installed.

```
# systemctl status NetworkManager
Unit NetworkManager.service could not be found
```

resolvectl status

```
# resolvectl status
Global
    Protocols: - LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS -DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (etho)
    Current Scopes:
        Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.178.1
DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1 192.168.178.1
```

netplan get

```
# netplan get
network :
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ethO:
      addresses :
      - "192.168.178.44/24"
      nameservers :
        addresses :
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 192.168.178.1
        search: []
      routes:
      - to: "default"
        via: "192.168.178.1"
```

checking DNS functionality using (`ping -4 xs4all.nl`):

```
# ping -4 xs4all.nl
ping: xs4all.nl: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

ping 1.1.1.1 -c 3

```
# ping 1.1.1.1 -c 3
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.178.44 icm_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.178.44 icm_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.178.44 icm_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

also `sudo systemctl status resolvconf.service`:

```
Unit resolvconf.service could not be found
```

What is the correct way to get network working?

P.S. I hope I did share enough info, if not I will add info

Comment: Try [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1295879/212930) - I would first make sure your box has network access, `ping 1.1.1.1 -c 3` should return connection - can you confirm?

Comment: added info, `resolvconf.service could not be found`

Comment: also during install I was unable to get IP address from DHCP server, so i am using fixed IP address

Comment: your ping to `1.1.1.1` indicates that this box has no internet, not that DNS is failing.

Comment: I will need to change the question to "How can I get network working?" But that's (in my case) a Windows issue   (All my Hyper-V stuff does not have network any more)

Comment: Again 1 hour wasted because something, that used to work, suddenly stopped working without a warning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here isn't that DNS resolution is failing, it's that you have no routes to the outside world. First, make sure you can reach your router from your VM:

```
ping 192.168.178.1 -c 3
```

If you can, then the issue is either some firewall, or another route being the issue. The fact that you cannot ping an IP Address external to the network, indicates that you have an incorrectly configured NIC, or Firewall. You may need to [disable your firewall](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-firewall-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa-linux) as a valid test.