# PR_IO_TIMEOUT_ERROR on serveral unrelated sites

Tags: networking, firefox, google-chrome

A few days ago, I got blocked from certain sites. At first I thought it was gov blocked me from using it. So I fake IP with VPN (use VPN-Gate service + OpenVPN client) to access those sites. However, as time passes, the number of sites getting blocked increases. So I decide to make a small list. I found that none of these sites are worth it to block, since they're mostly all about tech. The sites listed below return `PR_IO_TIMEOUT_ERROR` error in Firefox or `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in Chrome:

- medium.com (this guy was the first)
- linux.org
- itsfoss.com (can be accessible from Chrome only, but very slow)
- etc.

```
~$ nslookup medium.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   medium.com
Address: 127.0.0.1


~$ nslookup linux.org
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   linux.org
Address: 172.67.153.210
Name:   linux.org
Address: 104.21.80.209
Name:   linux.org
Address: 2606:4700:3033::6815:50d1
Name:   linux.org
Address: 2606:4700:3030::ac43:99d2


~$ nslookup itsfoss.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   itsfoss.com
Address: 172.67.75.102
Name:   itsfoss.com
Address: 104.26.8.105
Name:   itsfoss.com
Address: 104.26.9.105
Name:   itsfoss.com
Address: 2606:4700:20::ac43:4b66
Name:   itsfoss.com
Address: 2606:4700:20::681a:869
Name:   itsfoss.com
Address: 2606:4700:20::681a:969
```

I tried to access via `curl` but the result seems funny:

- medium.com => curl catch a localhost site of mine. (for a record, I did not override IP, or do anything with virtual host of Apache HTTP)
- [www.linux.org](http://www.linux.org) => got 301, but at least it's still working
- itsfoss.com => got only this `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Somehow, it cannot load the whole document due to IPv6. (got `* Immediate connect fail for 2606:4700:20::681a:869: Network is unreachable` when I use `-v` flag)

If I disable IPv6, I can only access itsfoss.com and nodejs.org. But the other sites are still inaccessible. Moreover, I don't know why but IPv6 is always turned on later even though I disabled it.

Flushing the DNS cache and restarting networking don't work. I also refer to [question #1241314](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241314) which seems to have a similar case but none of the solutions work.

Here is my machine config:

- Ubuntu 20.10 for ARM (Raspberry Pi 4) with custom DE.
- No Firewall (`ufw`)
- No Proxy Server
- DNS Servers: `192.168.43.1`
- Network is connected through my phone WiFi hotspot.
- Internet connection apps has test: w3m (fail like other browser), Firefox, Chromium, curl

Comment: I do not really see a Ubuntu question here.

Comment: I got this problem while using Ubuntu 20.10 ARM. If it shouldn't be here then where should I post this problem?

Comment: @ngdangtu The problem might be happening on a certain OS, but it’s not specific to Ubuntu. This all seems like a networking issue. Your [currently active question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1620627/167207) is a better place for this type question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 no DNS resolution when connected to openvpn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032476/ubuntu-18-04-no-dns-resolution-when-connected-to-openvpn)

Comment: What does *"curl catch a localhost site of mime"* mean?

Comment: @tripleee I used curl to load a single HTML page from the address. I'd expected it got error, but turn out, it return a HTML page which is served from my localhost (I built one for WordPress testing purpose).

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thanks for you support but my problem is more likely: No Ubuntu DNS resolution *after* connected to openvpn.

Comment: So "mime" is a typo and you are trying to say that `curl` retrieves a page served by your own HTTP server?

Comment: @tripleee Yes, HTTP (localhost) server. Now you told me, 'mime' is support to be 'mine' :p My bad.

Comment: I have this problem with the EasyJet website. I had to book a flight on my mother's computer. Using a VPN didn't work, using other browsers didn't work, clearing the cache and cookies didn't work...

Answer (score 6):

No reputation so answering with more details to follow up on easyJet site problem.

This usually occurs for me after attempting to navigate the site.  I see similar behaviour between Firefox and Chrome.  It is possibly related to whatever scripts easyJet are using.  In particular, I find after connecting normally to easyJet.com, when trying to select a flight date, the date picker fails to complete and has a 'Loading...' message which never clears, making progress impossible.  Reloads then get me the timeout error.  Chrome on Ubuntu behaves similarly, but takes much longer to timeout, if it ever does.

On Windows 10 Chrome & Firefox behave as expected with with the datepicker slide-in appearing quickly displaying calendars for date picking.  So, this seems to be a site scripting behaviour difference between Win 10 and Ubuntu browsers.  Whether this is web site, browser(s), script package (possibly Angular, but beyond my competence to be sure) or OS level difference is hard for me as a user to say.[Screen snap where the problems start on Ubuntu/Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdxUs.png)

Comment: You could ask this as a question yourself, as answers don't have follow-ups. I am actually having this issue as well

Comment: 13 days later and this is still a problem on the EasyJet site.

Answer (score 2):

No reputation so answering to just confirm: got the same problem with Firefox in Arch after logging in and trying to print the boarding pass. The connection broke after trying to open the flight (https://www.easyjet.com/de/secure/MyEasyJet.mvc/AllBookings). Since then even the login is not working anymore.

Chromium had no issues in my case.

`curl https://www.easyjet.com` got me an answer as well.